# Meteor - How can I pass data between helpers and events for a template?

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming

I'm a bit new to Meteor and something I'm having trouble with is reactive data -- particularly in instances where I need to change the data shown based on a mouse or keyboard event. Doing this kind of stuff the normal js way seems to give me trouble in meteor since everything I change gets re-rendered and reset constantly.

So, I thought I'd see if this would be a case in which I could use Meteor's Deps object, however I can't quite grasp it. Here's the code I'm using:

```
(function(){

    var tenants = [];
    var selectedTenant = 0;

    var tenantsDep = new Deps.Dependency;

    Template.tenantsBlock.tenantsList = function()
    {
        tenants = [];
        var property = $properties.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId(), propertyId: Session.get('property')});
        var tenancies = _Utils.resolveTenancies(property, true, null, true);

        for(var i = 0; i < tenancies.length; i++)
        {
            if(tenancies[i].tenancyId == Session.get('tenancy'))
            {
                tenants = tenants.concat(tenancies[i].otherTenants, tenancies[i].primaryTenant);
            }
        }

        tenants[selectedTenant].selected = 'Selected';

        tenantsDep.changed();

        return tenants;
    };

    Template.tenantsBlock.onlyOneTenant = function()
    {
        tenantsDep.depend();

        return tenants.length > 1 ? '' : 'OneChild';
    };

    Template.tenantsBlock.phoneNumber = function()
    {
        tenantsDep.depend();

        for(var i = 0; i < tenants[selectedTenant].details.length; i++)
            if(_Utils.getDynamicContactIconClass(tenants[selectedTenant].details[i].key) == 'Phone')
                return tenants[selectedTenant].details[i].value;

        return null;
    };

    Template.tenantsBlock.emailAddress = function()
    {
        tenantsDep.depend();

        for(var i = 0; i < tenants[selectedTenant].details.length; i++)
            if(_Utils.getDynamicContactIconClass(tenants[selectedTenant].details[i].key) == 'Email')
                return tenants[selectedTenant].details[i].value;

        return null;
    };

    Template.tenantsBlock.addedDate = function()
    {
        tenantsDep.depend();
        return _Utils.timeToDateString(tenants[selectedTenant].created);
    };

    Template.tenantsBlock.events({
        'click .Name': function(e, template)
        {
            tenantsDep.depend();
            var _this = e.currentTarget;
            var tenantName = _this.innerHTML;

            $(_this).addClass('Selected');
            $(_this).siblings().removeClass('Selected');

            for(var i = 0; i < tenants.length; i++)
            {
                if(tenants[i].name == tenantName)
                    tenants[i].selected = "Selected";
                else
                    tenants[i].selected = '';
            }
        }
    })


})();
```

^This seemed to be what they were getting at in the meteor documentation (http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency) for dependency.changed() and dependency.depend(), but all this does is give me an infinite loop.

**So can I modify the way I declare deps to get this to make data reactive? Is there a better way to do this all together?**

UPDATE:

Although I was skeptical to do so, I've been inclined to try to use Session.set/Session.get in a localized way. So, the next time I have to do this, I'll just do

```
Session.set('tenantsBlock' {tenants: [], selectedTenant: 0});
```

and then just access this variable from within helpers and event maps related to Template.tenantsBlock. That way they all have real time access to the data and they all get re-run when the data changes. Here's what I converted this script into (sorry these are both so large):

```
(function()
{
Template.tenantsBlock.created = Template.tenantsBlock.destroyed =function()
{
    _Utils.setSession('tenantsBlock', {
        tenants: [],
        selectedTenant: 0
    })
};

Template.tenantsBlock.tenantsList = function()
{
    var localContext = Session.get('tenantsBlock');
    localContext.tenants = [];
    var property = $properties.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId(), propertyId: Session.get('property')});
    var tenancies = _Utils.resolveTenancies(property, true, null, true);

    for(var i = 0; i < tenancies.length; i++)
    {
        if(tenancies[i].tenancyId == Session.get('tenancy'))
        {
            localContext.tenants = localContext.tenants.concat(tenancies[i].otherTenants, tenancies[i].primaryTenant);
            break;
        }
    }

    localContext.tenants[localContext.selectedTenant].selected = 'Selected';
    Session.set('tenantsBlock', localContext);

    return localContext.tenants;
};

Template.tenantsBlock.onlyOneTenant = function()
{
    var localContext = Session.get('tenantsBlock');
    return localContext.tenants.length > 1 ? '' : 'OneChild';
};

Template.tenantsBlock.phoneNumber = function()
{
    var localContext = Session.get('tenantsBlock');
    for(var i = 0; i < localContext.tenants[localContext.selectedTenant].details.length; i++)
        if(_Utils.getDynamicContactIconClass(localContext.tenants[localContext.selectedTenant].details[i].key) == 'Phone')
            return localContext.tenants[localContext.selectedTenant].details[i].value;

    return null;
};

Template.tenantsBlock.emailAddress = function()
{
    var localContext = Session.get('tenantsBlock');
    var selectedTenantDetails = localContext.tenants[localContext.selectedTenant].details;

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedTenantDetails.length; i++)
        if(_Utils.getDynamicContactIconClass(selectedTenantDetails[i].key) == 'Mail')
            return selectedTenantDetails[i].value;

    return null;
};

Template.tenantsBlock.addedDate = function()
{
    var localContext = Session.get('tenantsBlock');
    return _Utils.timeToDateString(localContext.tenants[localContext.selectedTenant].created);
};

Template.tenantsBlock.events({
    'click .Name': function(e, template)
    {
        var localContext = Session.get('tenantsBlock');
        var _this = e.currentTarget;
        var tenantName = _this.innerHTML;

        for(var i = 0; i < localContext.tenants.length; i++)
        {
            if(localContext.tenants[i].name == tenantName)
            {
                localContext.tenants[i].selected = 'Selected';
                localContext.selectedTenant = i;
            }
            else
            {
                localContext.tenants[i].selected = '';
            }
        }

        Session.set('tenantsBlock', localContext);
    }
})

})();
```

Comment: You can only set strings in Session variables. I still don't understand what you are trying to do with this code. Why can't you just put `localContext.tenants` in a collection and put `selectedTenant` in a session variable?

Comment: I don't know, man. The session variable seems to be storing an object just fine. The caveat is that I can't access it with Session.get('tenantsBlock.selectedTenant'), but it will still store the value of "tenantsBlock" as an object and will return it as such. That is, unless you know of a cross-browser issue with doing so.

Comment: I must admit that I'm not very comfortable with putting control data in the database. It seems like a clunky way to both store and retreive the data, plus if I did that for every template control in my app + all my normal db collections, I'd have at least 30 database collections. The Session variable just seems more efficient as a compromise to globally accessible control data.

Comment: You are probably right about Session; however you can create anonymous collections both on the client side and server side (not synced with Mongo.) Those will allow you to access nested fields where you can't with Session. I still don't understand what you mean by "control data", because I don't think you are explaining what your app needs to do very clearly.

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't know you could make anonymous collections. 

Sorry I haven't fully explained the app (or this part's implications) very well. It's a property mgmt app for landlords and this part of it basically needs to display all the tenants for any given tenancy at any given property in the system.

By "Control Data" I meant flags and other data used to maintain the state of a view. I guess the term "local context" may have been better.

Comment: Anonymous collections: `new Meteor.Collection(null)` for a client/server only collection and `new Meteor.Collection("name", {connection: null})` for a client/server synced collection that is in-memory only. Based on what you explained I would make a `Properties` collection and a `Tenants` collection that references `_id`s in properties. Then put any context in `Session` or an anonymous collection. That will get rid of all your cruft right here that is sifting through vanilla Javascript objects. Check out the app I linked up there, it has an example of doing this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to overcome the old-school way of doing it :) Meteor is a lot simpler than you think. **A good rule of thumb is that if you're using jQuery to manipulate any DOM elements, you're probably doing it wrong.** Additionally, if you're accessing any data without using the collection API, you'd better have good reason to do so.

In your case, you don't need to code up any manual dependencies at all. Manual dependencies are rarely needed in most Meteor applications.

The first thing you need to do is put all your tenants inside a `Meteor.Collection`, which will make them easier to work with.

```
Tenants = new Meteor.Collection("tenants");
```

Your `tenantsBlock` template should look something like this (modulo some different html elements):

```
<template name="tenantsBlock">
    <ol>    
    {{#each tenants}}
        <li class="name {{selected}}">
            <span>Primary Tenant: {{primaryTenant}}</span>
            <span>Other Tenants: {{otherTenants}}</span>
            <span>Phone Number: {{phoneNumber}}</span>
            <span>Email Address: {{emailAddress}}</span>
            <span>Added Date: {{addedDate}}</span>
        </li>    
    {{/each}}
    </ol>
</template>
```

Each document in `Tenants` should look something like the following:

```
{
    primaryTenant: "Joe Blow",
    otherTenants: "Mickey Mouse, Minnie Mouse",
    phoneNumber: "555-234-5623",
    emailAddress: "joe.blow@foo.com",
    addedDate: "2005-10-30T10:45Z"
}
```

Then, all the code you would need is just for the selection/deselection, and you can delete everything else:

```js
Template.tenantsBlock.tenants = function() {
    return Tenants.find();
};

Template.tenantsBlock.selected = function() {
    return Session.equals("selectedTenant", this._id);
};

Template.tenantsBlock.events({
    'click .name': function(e) {   
        Session.set("selectedTenant", this._id);
    }
});
```

Once again, I reiterate that you should never be doing DOM manipulations with Javascript when using Meteor. You just update your data and your templates will reactively update if everything is done correctly. Declare **how** you want your data to look, then change the data and watch the magic.

Comment: I'm thoroughly pleased to hear you oppose manual dom manipulation. It feels like it's fighting the framework, but I didn't quite think I had any other acceptable options.

That said, my use case is a lot more dynamic than I can really relay as there will be many properties each with many tenancies and all of which could be displayed on the very next page.

Nonetheless, what I'm inferring is that I should probably get over my fear of global variables, use Session without prejudice, and just unset it when the template is destroyed (to be re-rendered elsewhere).

Comment: I saw a talk by David Greenspan (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGQ-ax5cFnk) about adding support for a "Local reactive state" Maybe I'll just have to wait for that to get off the Session object.

Comment: It was not clear to me what you were trying to do because you didn't show any of your templates. What I've done is the simplest example that I inferred from your data. I can point you to one of my projects where there is live editing of a lot of data across many fields by many users at once, which you may find helpful: https://github.com/mizzao/CrowdMapper. One thing you may need to do is to have the tenancies and their properties in different collections, which you'll get comfortable manipulating as you get more familiar with Meteor.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that project.  Looks interesting.

Comment: I've been playing with meteor for a few weeks now, and this answer has helped me understand a lot of what meteor can do. thanks a lot!

Comment: better if you do it without session!

Answer (score 0):

> Meteor has really evolved since I posted this back in 2013. I thought
>   I should post a modern, superior method.

For a while now you've been able to create a `ReactiveVar` and now you can append those directly to templates. A ReactiveVar, similar to Session, is a reactive data store. ReactiveVar, however, holds only a single value (of any type).

You can add [ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) to the client side of your project by running this in your terminal from your app's root directory:

`$`**`meteor add reactive-var`**

This javascript shows how you can pass the variable between the template's `onCreated`, `onRendered`, `onDestroyed`, `events` and `helpers`.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated = function() {
    // Appends a reactive variable to the template instance
    this.reactiveData = new ReactiveVar('Default Value');
};

Template.myTemplate.events({
    'click .someButton': (e, template) => {
        // Changes the value of the reactive variable for only this template instance
        template.reactiveData.set('New Value');
    },
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    theData: () => {
        // Automatically updates view when reactive variable changes
        return Template.instance().reactiveData.get();
    },
});
```

This is superior for a few reasons:

1. It scopes the variable only to a single template instance. Particularly useful in cases where you might have a dozen instances of a template on a page, all requiring independent states.
2. It goes away when the template goes away. Using ReactiveVar or Session variables you will have to clear the variable when the template is destroyed (if it is even destroyed predictably).
3. It's just cleaner code.

Bonus Points: See [ReactiveDict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict) for cases in which you have many instances of a template on a page at once, but need to manage a handful of reactive variables and have those variables persist during the session.