# Cloning element instead of Rendering

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Currently I have a button when clicked, renders a template into the dom. I want the button to act more like a "clone element and append to parent element" button, but instead I only know how to "clone an element" by rerendering the template. It is a very expensive operation for rendering the template which I want to avoid.

Currrently I am doing this

```
Template.addWorkoutExercise.events({
  'click .add-exercise': function(e) {
    Blaze.render( Template.addWorkoutExercise , $( '#main' ).get(0) );
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

I want to know if there is a way to 'clone a element' without rendering, or if I can safely copy the view somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by using [Blaze.View](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_view) you can create a new view from a template without rendering it immediately. You will then be able to render it by either calling `Blaze.render` or `Blaze.toHTML`.

Comment: Having to call Blaze.render would be still perform the expensive operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using jquery.

Try this:

```
$('.element').clone().insertAfter('.element')
```

Comment: I will have to do more testing because Meteor can be finicky with using jQuery directly. Found more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934060/with-meteor-why-should-dom-manipulation-never-be-done-with-jquery